# How to implement inner select query in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my query structure

`$q1 = SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM table1  --- some join query --- WHERE condition ) temp_table;`

How can I implement this query in laravel like , `DB::table()` style ? I don't want to use like this `DB::select(DB::raw( q1 ))` .

Answer (score 1):

At this point I don't believe there's any way without using `DB::raw()`. But if you still want to build your subquery using the Query Builder, you could do something like this:

```
$subQuery = DB::table('table1')->join(...)->where(...)->toSql();
$result = DB::table(DB::raw("($subQuery) AS temp_table"))->get();
```